# How do I make the player move in the direction of the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, game-physics

This is my movement script

```
[SerializeField]
Vector3 movement;
[SerializeField]
KeyCode Up;
[SerializeField]
KeyCode Down;
public Rigidbody rb;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(Up))
    {
        rb.velocity += movement;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(Down))
    {
        rb.velocity -= movement;
    }
}
```

And This is my camera script

```
[SerializeField]
Transform transTarget;
[SerializeField]
float speed;
    
void Update()
{
    transform.position = transTarget.position;
    float h = speed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    transform.Rotate(0, h, 0);  
}
```

Basically, if I turn 180 with the camera and then press the up arrow to go forward, my player goes backward. I want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create 2 separate codes to create a first-person controller, that is what I think you are trying to do. You only have to do one that goes to the player. The camera has to be the child of the player and be inside of it. You have to tell the player that when you press Up or Down they have to move in that direction, First, you have to detect if the player is pressing up or down, with the function: Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") will give 1 when the Up is pressed and -1 when the Down is pressed and 0 if anything else is pressed. After that, you have to tell him witch id to go: transform.formward, in front of him, and multiply by the velocity you want.

```
[SerializeField]
Vector3 movement;
[SerializeField]
KeyCode Up;
[SerializeField]
KeyCode Down;
public Rigidbody rb;

public float Sensibility, Speed;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Speed = 100;
    Sensibility = 100;

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float h = Sensibility * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * h);

    rb.velocity = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Speed * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

But this is a very basic movement I recommend this video to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc.